# Merging datatables in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, merge

I have 2 identically constructed datatables.  The difference is where they get their data.

```
public DataTable dtPubSearchResultsFromTable(string sqlQuery)
{
    // Returns a datatable of publication search results based on data in table.
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Pages", typeof(string));
    da.Fill(dt);
    dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["publicationID"] };

    return dt;
}

public DataTable dtPubSearchResultsFromFiles(string sqlQuery, string safeKeyword)
{
    // Returns a datatable of publication search results based on PDF files.
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Pages", typeof(string));
    da.Fill(dt);
    dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["publicationID"] };

    return dt;
}
```

Since the second datatable is looking through PDF file for specific keywords, I populate the "Pages" column.  Then, I merge the 2 datatables EXPECTING to get a list of documents where the primary key "publicationID" is only listed once and the "Pages" column is updated with the list of page numbers from the 2nd datatable.  (I found this process in another question from 2011)

```
    var dtC = new DataTable("CombinationOfBoth");
    dtC.Columns.Add("publicationID",typeof(int));
    dtC.Columns.Add("PrimaryAuthor", typeof (string));
    dtC.Columns.Add("title", typeof (string));
    dtC.Columns.Add("rstiNumber", typeof(string));
    dtC.Columns.Add("linkToPublicationPDF", typeof(string));
    dtC.Columns.Add("publishDate", typeof(string));
    dtC.Columns.Add("approvalDate", typeof (string));
    dtC.Columns.Add("Pages", typeof(string));

    dtC.Merge(dt1,false,MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
    dtC.Merge(dt2, false, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
```

What I ACTUALLY get is a list of all of the document records and the ones that are in BOTH datatables are listed TWICE (once without page numbers, once with page numbers).

It seems I might be using the "MissingSchemaAction" improperly.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Why are you using data tables instead of a collection of model objects?

Comment: There is no need to use a DataTable here, working with a strongly typed model object would be much easier. Create a new class called `Publication` that contains all the properties (Id, author, title etc). Instead of returning a DataTable, return a `List<Publication>`.

Comment: Thanks Mason.  However, would I be able to bind that new class to a gridview?  I'm populating a gridview with the data in the table (or, trying to).

Comment: You bind the data normally. Ex: `MyGridView.DataSource = dtPubSearchResultsFromTable(arguments); MyGridView.DataBind();` but you in your GridView's attribute markup you would specify `ItemType="MyNamespace.Publication"` and then you can use strong typing to refer to the properties, as shown [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/asp-net-4-5-web-forms-features-strongly-typed-data-controls).

Comment: Yeah, that would be nice... HOWEVER, my employer is not quick to upgrade and we're still using .NET 3.5 :-(

Comment: Binding to the method that creates the datatable is pretty straightforward, how does one bind to the product of a "merged" datatable?

Comment: Do you want two way data binding, or just one way?

Comment: Not sure if this is 1-way or 2-way but I did it this way...

            gvPublications.DataSource = dtC;
            gvPublications.DataBind();

Answer (score 2):

Stab in the dark -In your original 2 tables you have defined the primary key but in the combined one you have not?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I WAS using MissingSchemaAction improperly.  It should have been MissingSchemaAction.Add

Answer (score 0):

Adding a primary key to the data table that merges the dt1 and dt2 should solve that issue. Add the following line before merging:

```
    dtC.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtC.Columns["publicationID"] };
```